# Write multiple lists to a JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

Assume I have the following lists

```
list1 = [{"created_at": "2012-01-31T10:00:04Z"},{"created_at": "2013-01-31T10:00:04Z"}] 
list2 = [{"created_at": "2014-01-31T10:00:04Z"}]
```

I can write the first list to a JSON file using `json.dump(list1,file,indent=2)` and the result is

```
[
  {
    "created_at": "2012-01-31T10:00:04Z"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2013-01-31T10:00:04Z"
  }
]
```

My question is, how do I append the contents of the second list? if I simple do `json.dump(list2,file,indent=2)`, it results in an invalid JSON file as below.

```
[
  {
    "created_at": "2012-01-31T10:00:04Z"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2013-01-31T10:00:04Z"
  }
][
  {
    "created_at": "2014-01-31T10:00:04Z"
  }
]
```

**Edit**: The lists are created dynamically by parsing about 8000 files. The above lists are just example. I could potentially be writing 8000 lists to the JSON file, so simple appending will not work.

Comment: If you mean "append" in the file sense (i.e., opening the file with mode `"a"`), I doubt you can.

Comment: As I understand you know how to extend lists in python and ask how to correct **dump** lists into json file. I think there is no possibility to do it as you want. Redesign your program if you can to have only one dump call

Comment: "simple appending will not work." Did you try it?

Comment: @LutzHorn lists are created inside a method. So when I am parsing a file, I don't have the list from previous files.
Even if I did have, the total data is ~50 gigs. Should I retain lists of that size throughout the program execution?

Comment: It doesn't sound like JSON is the right format for the job then. It's more for transfer than storage - basically for the reason you've mentioned: To append you need to parse all the data which, in this case, is unreasonable.

Comment: @DanielB The JSON file was going to be used to store the parsed data in MongoDB, but I guess I am better off storing directly to the database.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: list1 = [{"created_at": "2012-01-31T10:00:04Z"},{"created_at": "2013-01-31T10:00:04Z"}] 

In [3]: list2 = [{"created_at": "2014-01-31T10:00:04Z"}] 

In [4]: list1.extend(list2)

In [5]: json.dumps(list1)
Out[5]: '[{"created_at": "2012-01-31T10:00:04Z"}, {"created_at": "2013-01-31T10:00:04Z"}, {"created_at": "2014-01-31T10:00:04Z"}]'
```

or

```
In [8]: json.dumps(list1 + list2)
Out[8]: '[{"created_at": "2012-01-31T10:00:04Z"}, {"created_at": "2013-01-31T10:00:04Z"}, {"created_at": "2014-01-31T10:00:04Z"}]'
```

Comment: I have about 8000 files that I parse and create lists. These lists have to be written into 3 files, so appending will not work.

Comment: Then please rephrase your qustion and include all relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

When parse the files append (or extend) to a unique list and finally convert to JSON. Assume that your function for parse is `parse`.

```
>>> import json
>>> result = []
>>> for file in files:
...     result.append(parse(file))
...
>>> json.dump(result, file1, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a little lacking in the explanation given below that's why trying to make a point considered over here. 
A `Json` file can have a *single* parent element. Therefore, if at the first iteration, you dump 1st list then at the 2nd iteration, you will get the formatting error in the file. B/c Json demands these two lists to be wrapped inside one list/array before dumping.

Therefore, you store all lists in one list (either using appending or any other above-mentioned methods). And then you dump this aggregated list into your `Json` file. However, if you do not want to do so, you will have to create different files for your different lists.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, wanted valid json, not json lines, made custom solution:

```
# a+ is not good beacuse you can't seek before last end
open(out_path, 'r+' if path.isfile(out_path) else 'w+') as o:

# had multiple open calls, so little more complication

    for obj in data:
        for key in columns:
            with open_output(json_path, key) as o:
                o.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
                if o.tell() == 0:
                    o.write('[\n')
                else:
                    o.seek(o.tell() - 3)
                    o.write(',\n')
                json.dump({key: obj[key] if key in obj else columns[key]}, o, indent=2)
                o.write('\n]')
```

Output file is valid json after each write, indentation was no relevant for me, but one line per object was not readable so ended up with this.